# Every page turns my url into an IP address (Ubuntu Web Server)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, web-server, wordpress, web-hosting

This can probably be fixed quite easily. I tried to research and find the answer to this but couldn't find anything relevant.

Basically, I can access my website perfectly through its url. (ex. example.com)

Whenever I click a link, go to my `/wp-admin`, or go to any other page, my domain changes into the IP address. **(ex. instead of showing `example.com/about` it would show `192.111.223.4/about`)**

**How do I fix this?** Do I have to edit a file or can this be fixed by adding a domain record?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the virtualhost config block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**

Phew... This was a simple fix.

In the Wordpress dashboard I went to **Settings>>General** and then changed `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` into my actual domain instead of an IP.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention `/wp-admin`, chances are this is WordPress's doing.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

In `wp-config.php`, update or add:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Comment: Sort of. I just found the answer by going to Settings>>General and then changing the site url and address to my domain. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @exoro Yeah, that does the same thing, just via the UI. :)

Comment: This one is useful if you can't get into the WordPress admin because of the redirects.